# IF statement in ORDER BY Clause of a SELECT Statement in a SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a stored procedure that takes a bit parameter which if true orders by one column and if false orders by another column. How would I implement this?

Here is what I have so far

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CLICK10_GetCP]
    @switch AS BIT
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            acct_nbr,
            acct_name
        FROM
            acct
        ORDER BY 

    END
GO
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN @switch = 0 THEN Field1 END,
   CASE WHEN @Switch = 1 THEN Field2 END
```

Comment: You could write this as one case expression...
CASE WHEN @switch=0 THEN Field1 WHEN @switch=1 THEN Field2 END

Comment: If each CASE has a single THEN clause, you don't need to worry what type the fields are.

Comment: I apologize, this does in fact work as advertised, so +1. This (ORDER BY CASE @Switch  WHEN 1 THEN Field1 ELSE Field2 END;) doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

A crude way:

```
IF @switch = 1
  BEGIN
    SELECT
            acct_nbr,
            acct_name
    FROM
            acct
    ORDER BY acct_nbr
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT
            acct_nbr,
            acct_name
    FROM
            acct
    ORDER BY acct_name
  END
```

You should also be able to use CASE..WHEN I think:

```
SELECT
  acct_nbr,
  acct_name
FROM
  acct
ORDER BY
  CASE @switch
    WHEN 1 THEN acct_nbr
    WHEN 0 THEN acct_name
  END
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to build up the Query something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CLICK10_GetCP]
    @switch AS BIT
AS
DECLARE
@SQL nvarchar(max)


     SET @SQL N'SELECT
            acct_nbr,
            acct_name
    FROM
            acct
    ORDER BY '

if(@switch)
BEGIN
    @SQL = @SQL + ' acct_nbr '
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
    @SQL = @SQL + ' acct_Name '
END

Exec SP_ExecuteSQL @SQL
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure you can?  I'd end up doing this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CLICK10_GetCP]
    @switch AS BIT
AS
    BEGIN
        if @switch
        begin
            SELECT
                    acct_nbr,
                    acct_name
            FROM
                    acct
            ORDER BY 
                    acct_nbr
        end
        else
        begin
            SELECT
                    acct_nbr,
                    acct_name
            FROM
                    acct
            ORDER BY 
                    acct_name
        end
    END
GO
```

Comment: You can do it by using a CASE statement in the ORDER BY, but if the query is sufficently complex, your method will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

I thought you could change the parameter to an int, and sort by the column with that ordinal:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CLICK10_GetCP]
    @ordinal AS INT
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT
                acct_nbr,
                acct_name
        FROM
                acct
        ORDER BY @Ordinal

    END
GO
```

This throws an nice error (SQL2005):

> Msg 1008, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The SELECT item identified by the
>   ORDER BY number 1 contains a variable
>   as part of the expression identifying
>   a column position. Variables are only
>   allowed when ordering by an expression
>   referencing a column name.

Googling around found [this solution here](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/slightly-more-dynamic-order-by-in-sql-server-2005/) (SQL 2005 and up):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CLICK10_GetCP]
    @switch AS BIT
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT
                acct_nbr,
                acct_name
        FROM
                acct
        ORDER BY  CASE
            WHEN @switch = 0 THEN (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY acct_nbr, acct_name))
            WHEN @switch = 1 THEN (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY acct_name, acct_nbr))
         END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT
            acct_nbr,
            acct_name
    FROM
            acct
    ORDER BY case @switch when 1 then acct_name else acct_nbr end
```

Comment: This only works when acct_nbr and acct_name have the same datatype, or are convertable to each other.

Comment: True, but it's a useful technique.

Answer (score 0):

The most succinct approach is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CLICK10_GetCP]
    @switch AS BIT
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT
                acct_nbr,
                acct_name
        FROM
                acct
        ORDER BY 
                case @switch
                    when 1 then acct_nbr
                    when 0 then acct_name
                end

    END
GO
```

This may result in a poor execution plan for larger tables, or it may not work at all if acc-nbr is an int and acct-name is a varchar.

Wrapping two separate queries in IF / ELSE statements may perform noticeably better for larger datasets or be the only workable approach if the data types of the two columns are different.